# Should I chase down Squishys in teamfights with Ahri?

Tags: league-of-legends

My main character is Ahri. I manage to win my lane most of the times, but when it comes to Teamfights in Solo Q I am sometimes not quite sure how to react in teamfights.

Because of Ahris Mobility with her Ultimate, I actually interpret her role in teamfights like this:

Try to get to the enemy AD / AP Carry asap (with ult if it would take to long), burst him down, support the ongoing fight.

Now sometimes my burst isnt enough to kill the carry instantly, but it makes him leave the fight and run away.

In this case, should I try to chase him down or should I participate in the ongoing teamfight?

Comment: Honestly, it depends what kind of players you're playing against. Playing in high ELO games, it's good if you can get their main damage output out of position. There's no need to put yourself out of position also.

Comment: Fantastic question. I think this could be modified to almost any situation where you get their AD carry out of position... chase or go back to the team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely situational. If their AD carry is out of place and you have the window to take him out then by all means do so. But if he is in the back you will just get yourself killed. I think this is common sense. You will have to stay disciplined and act if you have the window of opportunity.

Otherwise just dps the one who is in your range. Prioritize squishies over tanks but if you only have a tank in range then hit him. Some damage is better than no damage.

Answer (score 2):

Don't leave your team. Chasing hard results in the enemy team turning around and killing you because you're out of position, or your team is now missing their AP carry. Take the 5v4 and push the win.

Comment: Well if the enemy team would try to get me down while I was chasing their carry they actually need to go for me, instead of "doing the teamfight" - which would leave my team with an advantage. Also if I would go back to the teamfight the enemy carry can do as well.
Dont get me wrong - I am not saying youre wrong, I just try to bring up my arguments, so you can deny them^^

Comment: @Toby it's really speculative on how far you're chasing, but if the entire enemy team chases you away (which they should if you over extend) they're inherently kiting your team. If they get a kill on you they don't have to commit to the 4v4.

Comment: @Toby your correct in that your being out of position would 'distract' the enemy team. However, 'distracting' the enemy team isnt your job, your tank or support should be doing that. or even your Melee AD character, as a AP Carry, your need to be focusing down the appropriate heroes in the enemy team. Your job is to Pew Pew. Period.